# How to show tags + posts for a custom taxonomy?

Tags: tags

I have a custom taxonomy (item_tags) for tags available to a cpt (item).

How do I list the name+description of each tag in that taxonomy, and the linked title+excerpt of the posts assigned to each tag?

I've looked at a lot of examples, but not yet found anything that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To list names and descriptions you can use [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/). That will return an array with all terms. An example would be:

```
global $post;    
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'item_tags',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<h2>' . $term->name . '</h2>';
        echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $term->description );
        $items = get_posts( array (
            'post_type' => 'item',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'item_tags',
                    'terms'    => $term->term_id,
                ),
            ),
        ) );
        foreach ( $items as $post ) {
            setup_postdata( $post );
            ?>
            <div>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. It's very helpful - I've been struggling with this for many hours. I've edited my original post to make clear that rather than whole posts it's just a linked title+excerpt that I want to display. And I'm trying to understand how to amend your code accordingly (but as a novice, I don't expect it to be a quick thing).

Comment: I've edited to show the linked post title and the excerpt, @glvr.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to be troublesome, but what I'm getting with the revised code is 'Tag name+description' - and in between each is 'Linked title+excerpt of the test page I'm using to display this'.

Comment: No problem @glvr. Give it a try now. Don't forget to add the initial `global $post;`

Comment: If it did help you don't forget to accept as the answer :) Thanks!

Comment: Answer accepted. :-) I'm wondering how easy it is to paginate the terms (not the posts for each term). From what I've seen, 'get_terms' doesn't accept 'posts_per_page', and pagination suggestions are beyond my understanding.